# ios multipart image upload, uploaded file is corrupted

Tags: ios, http, post, image-uploading, multipartform-data

I am making a multipart POST request to server and everything works fine, but the jpeg I'm uploading doesn't have the file extension and can't be opened (the file size is the same as orginal). I've tried this on tho different servers and the same error occured, so I'm assuming it's the issue of my app code.

```
let boundary = generateBoundaryString()
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: Urls.sendFileURL)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let body = NSMutableData()

    for (key, value) in params {
        body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
        body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")
    }


    let imageData: NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo, 0.8)

    body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"iosUpload\"; filename=\"iosUpload.jpg\"\r\n\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n")
    body.appendData(imageData)
    body.appendString("\r\n")
    body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")

    request.HTTPBody = body
```

I've tried my POST using posttestserver.com
 [this is the result](http://posttestserver.com/data/2015/05/12/momentum/07.44.46618948283)

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem: I upload a jpeg using `multipart/form-data`, and when I re-download the same file from the server it can't be opened by `Preview.app`, nor can it be used to create an instance of `UIImage`, because it is corrupted.

[image]

I opened both files side-by-side with FileMerge.app (included in Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/) and, to my surprise, the corrupted file had one extra empty line (CRLF) at the top; **otherwise, they are identical**:

Evidently, I am inserting an extra `\r\n` *just before* I append the contents of my file to the upload request's body.

I changed my upload code from this:

```
let body = NSMutableData()

body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"inputFile\"; filename=\"\(fileName)\"\r\n")
body.appendString("Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n\r\n") // !!!! THREE CRLF
body.appendData(fileData)    
body.appendString("\r\n--\(boundary)--")
```

...to this:

```
let body = NSMutableData()

body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"inputFile\"; filename=\"\(fileName)\"\r\n")
body.appendString("Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n") // !!!! TWO CRLF
body.appendData(fileData)    
body.appendString("\r\n--\(boundary)--")
```

...and now the downloaded file is a valid jpeg, identical to the one I uploaded.

So I suggest you open both versions of your file, side by side, and see what's changed.

*(FileMerge will complain that the "Files are not ascii.", but just ignore it and proceed.)*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ios, but you cannot find a library for constructing a multipart request, and you have to roll your own?

I can at least spot the following problems:

1)

```
body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"iosUpload\"; filename=\"iosUpload.jpg\"\r\n\r\n")
```

there's an extra `\r\n` here. it should be

```
body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"iosUpload\"; filename=\"iosUpload.jpg\"\r\n")
```

2)

```
body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
```

is missing the ending `--` here. it should be

```
body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")
```

Comment: thanks for your input, I've tried this, but that doesn't change anything.